# ember removeObserver and addObserver

Tags: ember.js

I have an array property named 'checked' that I'm observing and I want to temporarily disable observation while I update the property.  What is the correct syntax for removeObserver and addObserver?

```
        applyPreReqs: function() {
            var currentContent = this.get('content');
            currentContent.entitlements.forEach(function(entitlement) {
                if (entitlement.checked && entitlement.prerequisiteEntitlementIds !== undefined) {
                    entitlement.prerequisiteEntitlementIds.forEach(function(prereq) {
                        currentContent.entitlements.forEach(function(item) {
                            if (item.id === prereq && !item.checked) {
                                Ember.set(item, 'checked', true);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    currentContent.entitlements.forEach(function(item) {
                        if (item.id !== entitlement.id && item.checked) {
                            Ember.removeObserver('content.entitlements.@each.checked', this, this.applyPreReqs);
                            Ember.set(item, 'checked', false); 
                            Ember.addObserver('content.entitlements.@each.checked', this, this.applyPreReqs);
                        }
                    });
                }
        }.observes('content.entitlements.@each.checked')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't all that you are doing here but this is how you remove the array observer and then make your updates then add the observe back as the observe is fired.

```
applyPreReqs: function() {
    var currentContent = this.get('content');
    currentContent.entitlements.forEach(function(entitlement) {
        ....
    }
    currentContent.entitlements.removeArrayObserver(this);
}.observesBefore('content.entitlements.@each.checked')

applyPreReqs: function() {
    var currentContent = this.get('content');
    currentContent.entitlements.forEach(function(entitlement) {
        ....
    }
    currentContent.entitlements.addArrayObserver(this);
}.observes('content.entitlements.@each.checked')
```

I hope this helps
Cheers

Comment: Is there a way to observe a particular element in an array?  Like I want to watch the first element only (rest of the elements are ignored).  If the first element's checked property changes then I want to do something.

Comment: Would this be valid?  observes('content.entitlements.[0].checked')